# Exporting Postgresql database to OSM

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osmosis

I have osm data tables into postgresql .now i want to export it as .osm file. currently i am using osmosis to do that but somehow it is giving me error and i am not able to export it .

```
osmosis --read-pgsql host="localhost" database="Driving_14_02_2020" user="postgres" password="postgres"  --dataset-dump --write-xml file="myfile.osm"
```

error:
[image]

Comment: did you find any solution to this??